# PrimeNG table sticky header not working when rowGroupMode is specified

Tags: css, primeng, sticky, primeng-table

I am trying to show data in a PrimeNG table in a grouped manner. I am following the example given in their documentation https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-v13/table/rowgroup.

When I run the application I can see that the data is displayed in a grouped manner.

The problem that I am having is that when I scroll the grid, the header is not sticking. The row groups sticks. Please refer to the screenshots below,

Before scrolling,
[image]

After scrolling the header is not sticking,
[image]

Below is a screenshot of my table declaration,
[image]

I tried some solutions mentioned online of adding styling as below but it is still not working,
[image]

The PrimeNG version I am using is 13.4.1 and Angular 13

Can someone please let me know what I have missed.